# "member.user.tag" Tag is undefined

Tags: javascript, discord.js

"member.user.tag" is invalid. tried many things couldn't find A Solution. (near the bottom) Was wondering if I needed to use a .then but when I tried it, it only spammed the channel with random numbers and users.

```
 if (!Board) {
                profileModel.find({
                  serverID: message.guild.id
                }).sort([
                  ['allCatches', 'descending']
                ]).exec((err, res) => {
                  if (err) console.log(err);
              
                  let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .setTitle("All-Catches Leaderboard")

                  if (res.length === 0) {
                    embed.setColor("#ff0000");
                    embed.addField("No data found")
                  } else if (res.length < 10) {
                    embed.setColor("#ff0000");
                    for (i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
                      let member = message.guild.members.fetch(res[i].userID) || "User Left";
                      if (member === "User Left") {
                        embed.addField(`${i + 1}. ${member}`, `**All-Catches**: ${res[i].allCatches}`);
                      } else {
                        embed.addField(`${i + 1}. ${member.user.tag}`, `**All-Catches**: ${res[i].allCatches}`);
                      }
                    }
                  } else {
                    //more than 10 results
                    embed.setColor("#ff0000");
                    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                      let member = message.guild.members.fetch(res[i].userID) || "User Left";
                      let life = message.guild.members.fetch(res[i].userID);
                      if (member === "User Left") {
                        embed.addField(`${i + 1}. ${member}`, `**All-Catches**: ${res[i].allCatches}`);
                      } else {
                        embed.addField(`${i + 1}. ${member.user.tag}`, `**All-Catches**: ${res[i].allCatches}`);
                      }
                    }
                  }
              
                  message.channel.send(embed);
                })

            }
```

Comment: maybe use member.tag?

Comment: `member.user.tag` is the correct convention. Can you `console.log(member)` to check if it has a GuildMember object?

Comment: Came back with all my stats and some server stats, nothing about People. came back with like stats about the server boost etc.

Comment: So pretty Much it came back with all my roles and server banners, logo, name but never anything about members in a server @PerplexingParadox

Comment: What's `res` then?